# An orthonormal base of a set of waveforms

Tags: vectors, orthonormal, wave-equation

I'm trying to resolve an excercise of telecomunication that ask me to crate an ortonrmale base for this set of waveform.
$\ s_{1,2,3,4} (t) = \pm Acos(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0) \pm Asin(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$
$\displaystyle s_{5,6,7,8} (t) = \pm 3Acos(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0) \pm Asin(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$

It's clear to me that the 8 waveforms are depending with each other and they are linear combinations of $ \cos(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$ e $ \sin(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$, so, the orthonormal base will be of dimensions 2.

Now my problem is I'm not able to find the coefficients for the orthonormal base. According to my book, the results are

$\ \varphi_1 = \sqrt {2/T} cos(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$
$\ \varphi_2 = - \sqrt {2/T} sin(2 \pi f_0t+\varphi_0)$

where T is the symbol period $\ 0<t<T$

Someone can explain to me a general process to resolve this type of exercise?

Comment: $\varphi_1 = -\varphi_2$ then, which can't be right. Do you mean $sin$ for one of them? Your own thoughts look correct, you just need to normalize your $cos$ and $sin$ functions. Depending on the wording of your question, you may need to show that  your $cos$ and $sin$ functions are orthogonal too.

Comment: Yeah sorry, you were correct and I've fixed accordingly the question. My problem is, how do I need to proceed to find out first the orthogonal base to normalize?